# How can I read and convert my pdf file stored as bytea in postgresql through flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, pdf, bytea

I have one column in my postgreSQL table fails as email_pdf, in which I have saved my pdf file as bytea type. Now I wants to save/retrieve this through a function in my flask app.

I am getting error as seen in the image.
[image: Error image when opening the pdf file saved through above function.]

```
select email_pdf from fails where fail_id = 9
```

My flask function looks as below :

```
@app.route('/download_file')
def downloadFile ():
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    s = "select email_pdf from fails where fail_id = 9"
    cur.execute(s)
    list_data = cur.fetchall()
    return send_file(BytesIO(list_data[0][0]), as_attachment=True,download_name="new.pdf")
```

I am able to save file when I redirect to /download_file but when I am opening it. it is showing nothing or error. Can someone please help me what is wrong in my code or how can I download and convert binary data into pdf file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you getting the PDF data into the `email_pdf` field?

Comment: I am using `pdf.output("Fail " + str(fail_id) + ".pdf")` function of `FPDF` library and then inserting into the table with `curr.execute` function.

Comment: And the `cur.execute` code is ? Also what Python version?

Comment: I could not replicate.  So: 1) The data is not being put into the field correctly. 2) `email_pdf` is not the data type you think it is 3) `fail_id = 9` is not actually returning anything. Try: `select length(email_pdf) from fails where fail_id = 9` in `psql`.

Comment: curr.execute code is:
`curr.execute("INSERT INTO fails (fail_id, dept_id, fail_name, emp_id, validate_flag, task_process_id, email_pdf) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (fail_id, x[4], x[3], x[5], validate_flag, task_process_id, pdf.output("Fail " + str(fail_id) + ".pdf")))`

Comment: And when I am using 
`s = "select email_pdf from fails where fail_id = 9"
    cur.execute(s)
    data = cur.fetchall()
    print(data[0])`
I am getting output as:
`[<memory at 0x00000244C1FF3DC0>]`

Comment: 1) Add your code to your question in properly formatted manner. 2) You did not report on what `select length(email_pdf) from fails where fail_id = 9` in `psql` returns? 3) What is `pdf.output("Fail " + str(fail_id) + ".pdf")` doing? I know the overall procedure works for me. Your case is going to need a step by step troubleshooting on your part: a) Prove the PDF is actually being created. b) Prove it is being inserted into field. c) Prove it is being retrieved from field.

Comment: Yes @AdrianKlaver you were right, I was not able to insert pdf data into psql table. Anyways I have found another way to do it, now I am not saving file data in any column rather I am generating it dynamically by saving data into table then generating pdf file from that using `fpdf` library. Thank you guys, I love this community :).